# Yii framework: AuthManager

Tags: php, yii

I am following this litle guide, how to set up an RBAC. [This guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/65/how-to-setup-rbac-with-a-php-file/)
I got stuck at this point :

$ cp auth.txt auth.php

whats the point of doing this? Why i cant just make a php file and put my code in there. This is just making the same file with the .php ext.

So i did everything in this guide. Now i have the following error:  Unknown authorization item "reader". I get this when i try to log in. Any idea? Got stuck for a few hours now.

Comment: why are you not using Rights as RBAC manager...thats much easier..

Comment: i dont know, i am a newbie to yii, and i found this kinda easy.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. auth.php file must be in the data folder. And should have `<?php ?>` tags.